# How to create query string using Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my mvc3 razor project my I have action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("ActionLinkName","Count","Home",new{id = 3})
```

This generates `localhost/Home/Count/3`

but I want it to create `localhost/Home/Count?id=3`

What changes in route should I make ?

Comment: It's the 'id' parameter in your default route that's telling mvc to create the url like that.  You could use something other than 'id', or change the route to expect a differently named parameter.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: WHY would you want that?

Comment: my client wants that kind of link.

Comment: well, whatever the client wants... but that seems backwards to me. MVC makes it easy for URLs to be more user and SEO friendly, and query strings just aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the default route that's used with new MVC projects includes an `{id}` segment. Removing that segment from your default route will make your existing code produce a query string.

Change this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
    );
```

To this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                     // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}",                       // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the default (fallback) route that Asp.Net registers is including an `{id}` parameter in the url pattern:

```
// Default
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Your generated url adheres to this fallback pattern (`{controller}/{action}/{id}`) and appends your `id` using `/{id}`.

You'll need to register a custom route **before the default route** to exclude the `{id}`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Count",
    url: "Home/Count",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Count" }
);
```

You can also try to remove the `{id}` from the default pattern (if it won't affect other actions) or change your `id` parameter in the `Count` action to a different name.

Answer (score 0):

remove `{id}` from default config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { 
            controller = "Home", 
            action = "Index", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

TO

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { 
            controller = "Home", 
            action = "Index" }
    );
}
```